# CSS Optimization Tools

Tags: css, optimization

Are there any downloadable programs that will perform common CSS optimization techniques? Looking for something not online.

Comment: What is a CSS optimization? Gzipping the file should be fine.

Comment: looking for duplicate classes, un-used classes, duplication, etc

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what kind of optimization exactly you're after, and what kind of tool you want:

- [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/): CSS parser and optimizer
- [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/): Firefox add-on that can find unused CSS selectors
- [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/): a PHP app that combines, minifies and gzips your site's CSS and Javascript
- [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html): the Apache module you should be using to gzip your content
- [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/): Firebug extension (like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)) that checks for various website optimization techniques, but can also minify your CSS for you
- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/):  Java tool to minify Javascript and CSS

Answer (score 6):

Yahoo has some excellent tools you can use for minifying JavaScript and CSS:

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

It is Java-based and open source.

From the link:

> **How does the YUI Compressor work?**
>
> The YUI Compressor is written in Java
>   (requires Java >= 1.4) and relies on
>   Rhino to tokenize the source
>   JavaScript file. It starts by
>   analyzing the source JavaScript file
>   to understand how it is structured. It
>   then prints out the token stream,
>   omitting as many white space
>   characters as possible, and replacing
>   all local symbols by a 1 (or 2, or 3)
>   letter symbol wherever such a
>   substitution is appropriate (in the
>   face of evil features such as eval or
>   with, the YUI Compressor takes a
>   defensive approach by not obfuscating
>   any of the scopes containing the evil
>   statement) The CSS compression
>   algorithm uses a set of finely tuned
>   regular expressions to compress the
>   source CSS file. The YUI Compressor is
>   open-source, so don't hesitate to look
>   at the code to understand exactly how
>   it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET then just use StyleManager. It automatically combines and minifies your CSS and it's easy to integrate. You can get it at [gStyleManager.com](http://www.gstylemanager.com).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Yahoo! Developer Network, especially the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

You might also want to look at Firebug and [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/5369) or [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/). They can analyze for inefficient use of CSS (you'd still have to fix the CSS yourself, though),